# multiple dialog dispose

Tags: dialog, dispose, lwuit

In lwuit, How can I dispose multiple dialogs by using single?
If there is 2 dialogs are shown (One over another) and if I dispose first Dialog then next dialog . But I need to close(dispose) both dialogs  and display Form. Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the same `Dialog` to show that?

I mean. Show the first `Dialog`. After this, show the next `Dialog` using the same object (clean `TextArea`, `Label`, everything that you are using for showing the info inside the `Dialog`) and put the new data. After that close this only one `Dialog`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, as i believe it is unintended behavior. I passed a parentForm parameter to the dialog and then i just use parentForm.showBack(); after i call dialog.Dispose(). But you need to be sure that either the dialog is visible or the parentForm so as not to overide an unrelated screen if the user closes and quickly moves to another form.

```
currDialog.dispose();
if(currDialog.isVisible() || parent.isVisible())
         parent.showBack();
```

I guess another solution could be using a singleton class for the dialog calls.